# AS400 C#.net inserting new record problems

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-midrange

I am trying to build a C#.net program that works like a RPG Subfile on the AS400.

Have the general subfile part working. I can display and then edit and update existing records.

Am blowing up in my code where I am trying to insert a new record. Blowing up on the

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

If you want to see how this works without the insert go to

http://144.162.90.78/thomas/

Look at the Website1a

Here is the code.

```
using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("WebForm1a.aspx");
    }
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cssc =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

        String connString = cssc["FTWAS400"].ToString();

        iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(connString);

        conn.Open();

        iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(
                   "insert into tburrows.qcustcdt (cusnum, init, lstnam, street, city, state, zipcod, cdtlmt, chgcod, baldue, cdtdue) values (@cusnum, @init, @lstnam, @street, @city, @state, @zipcod, @cdtlmt, @chgcod, @baldue, @cdtdue)", conn);


        cmd.DeriveParameters();

        cmd.Parameters["@cusnum"].Value = Request["txtCUSNUM"];
        cmd.Parameters["@init"  ].Value = Request["txtINIT"];
        cmd.Parameters["@lstnam"].Value = Request["txtLSTNAM"];
        cmd.Parameters["@street"].Value = Request["txtSTREET"];
        cmd.Parameters["@city"].Value   = Request["txtCITY"];
        cmd.Parameters["@state"].Value  = Request["txtSTATE"];
        cmd.Parameters["@zipcod"].Value = Request["txtZIPCOD"];
        cmd.Parameters["@cdtlmt"].Value = Request["txtCDTLMT"];
        cmd.Parameters["@chgcod"].Value = Request["txtCHGCOD"];
        cmd.Parameters["@baldue"].Value = Request["txtBALDUE"];
        cmd.Parameters["@cdtdue"].Value = Request["txtCDTDUE"];


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();

        btnBack_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Thomas

Comment: When you say it's "blowing up" what exactly do you mean? I expect an exception is being thrown - and the details of that exception will be very important.

Btw, are you aware of "using" statements to avoid you having to call cmd.Dispose() and conn.Close() explicitly?

Comment: Jon:

What I get is an "OverflowException unhandled by User Code

"The parameter is not in the range of valid values".

Under troubleshooting tips I get 

"Make sure you are not dividing by zero"

Hope this helps.

Thomas

Comment: The entire code for this is at Http://144.162.90.78/thomas/notes

Comment: I cannot get the notes folder to show, but if one looks at website2 and webform1a you can see what I am doing.

Comment: Mike:

Can you call me at 469 693 2533. Have tried to send you an email from what I found on your website. 

The suggestion "perhaps I did it wrong" now causes the code segment to not compile. 

Thomas

thomas.burrows.1957@gmail.com
PS: I can pay if you can help me out here.

Comment: No need to pay me. This is a community where we work together. Someday I may have a question you can answer and then you have paid me.

Answer (score 3):

There is another option within the

```
cmd.Parameters["@cusnum"].Value = field;
```

to specify the field type. Use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cusnum", iDB2DbType.iDB2Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(field);
```

instead. This should convert your data types properly. You will need to change the iDB2Decimal to the proper field type if not decimal.

Comment: Do not use 'cmd.DeriveParameters()' with this solution!